# Decomposing a Boolean algebra into homogeneous parts with respect to a cardinal function

Tags: cardinals, boolean-algebra

In the paper "On Families of Mutually Exclusive Sets" by Erdős and Tarski, it is claimed that for every Boolean algebra $B$ and a nondecreasing cardinal function $f\colon B \to \mathrm{Card}$, $B$ can be expressed as a direct product of $f$-homogeneous Boolean subalgebras. A subalgebra $A$ of $B$ is called $f$-homogeneous if $f(A \setminus \{0\})$ is a singleton. The proof would goes like this.

Let $H \subset B$ be a maximal family of pairwise disjoint $f$-homogeneous elements of $B$. $H$ exists by Teichmüller–Tukey lemma. For every nonzero $b \in B$, there exists $a \le b$ such that $B\restriction a$ is $f$-homogeneous, for you can pick any $a \le b$ such that $f(a) = \min f(B \restriction b \setminus \{0\})$. Hence there exists $h \in H$ which is not disjoint with $a$ and, a fortiori, $b$. This implies that the Boolean algebra homomorphism $\phi\colon B \to \prod_{h \in H} B \restriction h$ given by $b \mapsto (b \land h)_{h \in H}$ is injective.

If $B$ is a complete Boolean algebra, $\phi$ is indeed surjective. But I don't see why in noncomplete cases. Is the claim correct?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/122802/2060) notion of direct sum is used? Then no completeness is needed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think that's right.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But still using the direct sum I don't get how $B$ is generated by them. For example $2^{\aleph_0}$ has a natural partition into $\aleph_0$ elements but it doesn't generate the characteristic function of even numbers.

Comment: What's your $f$ for that potential counterexample $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think the cardinality of the support(or cardinality itself, if seen as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$) suffices.

Comment: support? What do you mean? Make the  example more concrete if you can..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  I was meaning that if $2^{\aleph_0}$ is seen as the set of every function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0, 1\}$, the cardinality of the $x$s where $f(x) \neq 0$ would suffice. If seen as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ it is the cardinality function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131220/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-ris).